# Dictionary keys-items to objects in python

Tags: python, dictionary, object

Many times I make a data checkpoint on my code, so I start from there next day without running the code again. I do that by saving the python objects into a dictionary and then to pickle. e.g.

`saved_dict = { 'A' : 'a', 'B' : ['b'], 'C' : 3} etc`

And when I load it i do:

`A = saved_dict['A']`

`B = saved_dict['B']`
... etc

I wonder if there is a way to do that in an automated way, maybe with a for loop, instead of writing them all one by one.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign directly to [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), without the need of `exec`, which could be a source of security issues.

```
>>> saved_dict = { 'A' : 'a', 'B' : ['b'], 'C' : 3}
>>> for k,v in saved_dict.items():
...     globals()[k] = v
... 
>>> A
'a'
>>> B
['b']
>>> C
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a terrible idea and there are definetly better solutions for your problem itself (for example not storing a dict). But I shall entertain this:

```py
for k in saved_dict:
   exec(f"{k} = {saved_dict[k]}")
```

Note that you need `exec` and not `eval`, as assignments are not expressions.
This is an attrocity and im going to hell for this crime.

Comment: Thanks!
why is it a bad idea? (of course I do it in a draft way)
What other alternatives are available?

Comment: Using exec is pretty terrible on its own, but could you explain why you dont want to run your code again? Does it take that long? Also if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so other people find it

Comment: Also I had `i` instead of `k`, which is fixed now

Comment: Check the new answer that someone else made, its way more pythonic than what the hell I did